# Get Internal Storage custom directory location

Tags: android, storage, internal

I' am trying to get the location of my Internal Storage dynamically but having issues with it. The following is my code that am currently working with:

```
Context context = this;
File dir = context.getDir("appdata", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
File file = new File(dir, "name.txt");
System.out.println( file.toString() );
```

The return path from the print is `/data/data/com.example.application.form/app/name.txt` but I want `Internal Storage/appdata/name.txt`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are actually looking for external storage. The dir you are using is app sandbox location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
```

instead

```
File dir = context.getDir("appdata", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```